# Salesforce apex:inputField

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am new to salesforce and Apex . In apex:input field i have use html-maxlength it is working fine but in IE11 it is showing message on submit button .

[image]

Please suggest how can i find thi css Class or how can i change it style

```
<apex:inputField id="phonePrimary" value="{!primaryContact.Phone_Number__c}"  onKeyDown="isNumberOnlyForPrimary(event);" onKeyUp="formatPrimaryPhoneNumber(event);" styleClass="form-control phonePrimary" html-maxlength="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do u use the max-length attribute? An apex:inputField represents the same "attributes" like the corpesponding salesforce field. So when your field in your object is e.g. Text(10) than you automatically can store only up to 10 chars.

Comment: Could you please share me link or url and i have use max-length attribute show that user cannot enter phone number more than 10 digit from front end

Comment: Hi I have used $('.phonePrimary').on("invalid", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});  and it is working fine. thanks for your help